# How to make a program wait in python 3.6.2, pygame 1.9.3

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, pygame

I have been trying to make a simple rpg game with a scrolling background and a character that when the arrow keys are presses he moves. I have successfully made the man change the direction he is facing but it he doesn't move his feet. This is where the problem started. I tried adding a `time.sleep(0.3)` to the code and the different walking sprites but my game crashed. This is the walking logic code.

```
if manDir == 1:
    manPos[1] += 2
    gameDisplay.blit(PlayerFrontBack.playerFrontWalk1, (playerWidth, playerHeight)) #PlayerFrontBack is a previously declared function to load in the players front and back sprites
    time.sleep(0.3)
    gameDisplay.blit(PlayerFrontBack.playerFrontWalk2, (playerWidth, playerHeight))
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Thank you for reading and happy coding!

Comment: Never use `time.sleep` in games on the main thread. The game library will almost definitely have some kind of wait function of its own. Did your search "pygame wait" or "pause"?

Comment: If you want to control the animation speed take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45185093/6220679), otherwise explain a bit more detailed what you're trying to do and post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).